# Install grub using custom boot-loader ID, e.g "MyUbuntu"

Tags: grub2

I'm able to reinstall grub using default boot-loader ID "**ubuntu**"

But if I use custom name like "**MyUbuntu**" I cannot make a successful grub installation.

Test installation on a well-booting Ubuntu 18.04:

1: Delete existing grub:

`rm -r /boot/efi/EFI/*`

2: Install new grub:

`grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id=MyUbuntu /dev/sda`

2: Update grub:

`update-grub`

System now boots into the Grub console.
The EFI was seeing the new boot entry in the boot menu just fine.

[image]
[image]

Just took a peak into the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, it still says:
`menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu.....`

Comment: I have a custom entry, but it really does not work as UEFI entry really uses /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg not my /EFI/Ubuntu_18_04/grub.cfg. So I only have one working UEFI entry and have to edit the grub.cfg in the ESP if I want to change default boot. And then I use grub to boot other installs.

Comment: So is it a bug or by design?

Comment: It is by design, but developers have for several years said they want to fix it. Obviously not a priority.

Comment: Any workarounds? I need to have a non-default EFI folder? Been looking in the .cfg file but it didn't get me anywhere?

Comment: I believe I saw someone who had two FAT32 formatted partitions and moved boot flag back & forth, changing which was ESP. But grub can boot any install you want either directly, chainload or configfile (load another grub).

Comment: I wonder if you could just use a non-ubuntu version of `grub-install` e.g.boot from Archlinux live.iso. Maybe the `bootloadèr-id` will not be hardcoded into the .efi file.And if so, will Ubuntu boot at all?

Comment: If you experiment let us know. I did try Fedora once, it allowed me to install directly to sdb, and found my Ubuntu installs. Did not try any other experiments

Comment: It sure did work! :-)
I used `grub-install` from Debian buster and my bootloader-id is now `ubuntu2`
I could imaging secure-boot might not work. It seems whole reason for Ubuntu hardcode the ID is the bootloader in signed and therefore cannot be modified, well you can, but then it would not be signed anymore. . But I don't use secure boot any way so I don't care.

Comment: I use your method for years and I haven't any problem at all, for me it works out of the box. You say you don't use secure boot, but your menu entry points to `shimx64.efi`. My entries point to `grubx64.efi` (I don't use secure boot too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I ran into **systemd-boot** as boot-loader I've never looked back at GRUB.
**systemd-boot**, is in my view, way more stable and has a much better way of configuration.
And by "stable" I mean it's not as vulnerable as GRUB. GRUB is so easy to break.
Just adding a new disk to your box can give you big trouble (because of maybe identical boot-loader ID's that you cannot change etc.)

Only downside of **systemd-boot** is the lack of secure-boot support, but that's not an issue for me, and that your kernel must be located in the EFI partition, instead of root partition, as it is the case with GRUP.

With **systemd-boot** I got back full control of the boot-process...YES

It should be the default boot-loader instead of GRUB.

**UPDATE**, How to do (Debian/Ubuntu):
(This is a rather superficially guide, but I hope it will get you started. Other sources: [Arhlinux..](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot), [freedesktop..](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/systemd-boot/) and [readme..](https://github.com/ivandavidov/systemd-boot/blob/master/README.md))

**1**: First copy the kernel files from you root partition, e.g. `/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-8-amd64` and `/boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-8-amd64`, to your EFI partition. You can place them in a subfolder of your choice or even in root-folder if you like.

**2**: Many guides says you need access to the EFI variables, but I'm not sure if this is needed. But to test if you have, run `efivar --list`.

To Install if missing: `apt install efivar`

**3**: Install **systemd-boot** loader to the EFI partition: `bootctl --path=/mnt/efi install` (use you own path to your mounted EFI partition)

**4**: Edit the file `/mnt/efi/loader/loader.conf` to something like:

```
timeout 5
# default 6a9857a393724b7a981ebb5b8495b9e-*
```

(haven't figured out how to use the auto-added UUID in the file, so I just marked it out)

**5**: Each file in `/mnt/efi/loader/entries/*.conf` correspond to at boot-entry in the **systemd-boot** menu. So to add your current OS make a file looking something like:

```
title      Debian 9 :-)
linux      /debian9/vmlinuz-4.9.0-6-amd64
initrd     /debian9/initrd.img-4.9.0-6-amd64
options    root=UUID=084917b7-8be2-4e86-838d-f771a9902e08`
```

(Modify the path to the kernel files you copied in step 1. Modify the UUID to the filesystem-UUID of you root partition (use Linux command `lsblk -o name,uuid`)

**General info:**

**bootctl** will install two bootloader-files in your EFI partition:

```
../BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
../systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
```

These files are identical. Your EFI bios on your motherboard moust boot/point to one of them. Either do it in the BIOS directly or use the Linux command `efibootmgr....`

To add a new boot entries just create a new `/mnt/efi/loader/entries/*.conf` files which point to the right kernel files and root partition.

The kernel files MUST be located on the EFI partition (FAT32). 

The EFI partition must be sized accordingly. I think the kernel files for e.g. Debian/Ubuntu is about 50-60MB. So if you have two installations you need 120MB.

Comment: I agree.....just limited time right now, but I'll add how in short words so people can get started

Comment: I even did it on a USB flash. It has often been trouble full with GRUB. Now it should be easy to make an bootable USB key with multiple installation OS: Win10, WinSrv, Debian, Arch, Ubuntu etc.I always have my bag full of individual USB keys for each OS, now I can have one with good performance `Mushkin Impact 64GB USB 3.0` (> 100MBs :-))

Comment: You can boot which ever Linux you like (You "normal" ubunto on HDD, Live for USB, any whould do. It doesn't even have to be the same distro. I assume all have the systemd-boot package available.
You don't have to do all the painful chroot-thing as with GRUP. Just copy the  kernel-files to EFI, install systemd-boot, modify/create the text-files, point EFI-bios to the need bootloader file....that's it :-)

Comment: I doesn't matter, just boot any Linux. But if you boot from a USB you have to mount the EFI and root partition on the HDD to be able to access it.
But if you boot your installed Ubuntu the EFI partition is already mounted to /boot/EFI.

Comment: Nice :-)
What error did you get? 
And which file did you point add for Win10...haven't tried that myself yet

Comment: But which Win10 boot file did you point to in you entry file?

Comment: `title W10` `efi /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmfg.efi` or similar. only two lines.. did not remember the path exactly.. now with phone

Comment: Yea, not so difficult to get running when you know how, haha

Comment: I guess you can....(haven't tried either yet).

Comment: Trying to "burn" Windows ISO to partition on USB flash-drive and create boot entry in systemd-boot EFI partition, thread link [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141890/burn-windows-iso-to-partition-on-usb-flash-drive). Making the utimate bootable multi-OS USB flash (Linux, Win10 in ENG and local languages, Win server etc).

Comment: Hi, Sorry, I dont have any clue on this.. I have recently tried installing Ubuntu first without grub and then made Windows10 bootable USB from Ubuntu and Succesfully Installed Windows10

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned by gdeff](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129269/install-grub-using-custom-boot-loader-id-e-g-myubuntu#comment2090505_1217666), to install Grub with a custom `--bootloader-id`, use also the option `--no-uefi-secure-boot`.  For example:

```
grub-install                \
  --target=x86_64-efi       \
  --no-uefi-secure-boot     \
  --bootloader-id=MyUbuntu  \
  /dev/sda
```

Also, make sure that SecureBoot is disabled on your system.

**Explanation**

You only need to read the below (unfortunately lengthy) explanation if you want to better understand the interactions between `grub-install`, `grubx64.efi`, `grub.cfg`, and SecureBoot.

- SecureBoot will only boot an `.efi` file that is cryptographically signed by Microsoft.
- On an Ubuntu system, the file `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` typically comes from one of two places:
- Option 1:  `grubx64.efi` is a static, unchanging, Microsoft-signed, SecureBoot-compatible “binary blob” Grub bootloader provided by Canonical.  This is the default option.
- Option 2:  `grubx64.efi` is created on your system when you run `grub-install`.  In this case, `grubx64.efi` is not signed and, therefore, is not compatible with SecureBoot.

With option 1 (Canonical-provided, SecureBoot-compatible `grubx64.efi`):

- There will typically be two `grub.cfg` files.
- Phase-1 `grub.cfg` at `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`
- Phase-2 `grub.cfg` at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- The phase-1 `grub.cfg` file contains the information that `grubx64.efi` will need in order to find and read the phase-2 `grub.cfg` file.
- The path for the phase-1 `grub.cfg` file, `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`, cannot be changed.  Changing this path would require changing `grubx64.efi` itself.  Changing `grubx64.efi` would invalidate the signature, rendering it incompatible with SecureBoot.

With option 2 (custom-made `grubx64.efi`):

- There is no phase-1 `grub.cfg` file, because ...
- All the configuration information that the custom-made `grubx64.efi` bootloader needs in order to find and read the phase-2 `grub.cfg` file (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) is embedded directly inside the custom-made `grubx64.efi` file itself.
- This is possible because the custom-made `grubx64.efi` bootloader is not compatible with SecureBoot and therefore does not need to be signed by Microsoft.

If you run `grub-install` **with** `--bootloader_id=` and **without** `--no-uefi-secure-boot`, then:

- `grub-install` will use the Microsoft-signed, provided-by-Canonical `grubx64.efi` file.  (This is option 1, above.)
- This `grubx64.efi` file and a custom-made phase-1 `grub.cfg` file will be installed in: `/boot/efi/EFI/$bootloader_id/`
- However, upon boot, the `grubx64.efi` file will attempt to read `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` (as this path cannot be changed).
- If `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` does not exist, then the boot will fail.
- If `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` does exist, but comes from a different installation of Ubuntu on the same system, then the boot may fail, or `grubx64.efi` may boot that other Ubuntu system instead of the desired Ubuntu system.
- Aside:  In this case (i.e where `--no-uefi-secure-boot` is absent), it could be argued that: `grub-install` should generate an error (or at least a loud warning) rather than silently installing a very-probably-incorrectly-configured bootloader.

Alternatively, If you run `grub-install` **with** `--no-uefi-secure-boot`, then:

- `grub-install` will create a custom-made (and unsigned) `grubx64.efi` file.
- There will be no phase-1 `grub.cfg` file in `/boot/efi/EFI/$bootloader_id/`.
- This `grubx64.efi` file will, all by itself, be able to find and read the phase-2 `grub.cfg` file at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

As mentioned at the top of this answer, if you use `--no-uefi-secure-boot`, you will (of course) need to make sure that SecureBoot is turned off on your system.

Comment: Is there a way to persist the value that was passed to --bootloader_id=foo ? (and the use of --no-uefi-secure-boot) Because even minor updates to grub can trigger a grub-install with default values. So the answer is only partially complete if the setup isn't persistent. (still very useful for a user that can deal with fixing grub from time to time)

Comment: @tuxayo - There may or may not be a way to persist the value of `--bootloader-id` and `--no-uefi-secure_boot`.  I don't know.  The only time I can remember Grub failing for me is after I did an in-place upgrade from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10.  (I almost never do in-place upgrades.)  I wondered why Grub failed, but did not investigate.  I just reinstalled Grub manually.  Your comment may explain why that failure happened.  The maintainers of the Debian/Ubuntu `grub` packages might know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple workaround. After running `grub-install` with `--bootloader-id`, run `grub-install` without any arguments. It will create an ubuntu entry. Delete it if you want to, but now your id is going to work "magically". Very annoying, seems to be an old bug. Hope I helps.

Comment: this will appear to work, but if "ubuntu" entry is deleted then the custom bootloader-id will not work. No need to re-run grub-install without params; just disable uefi secure boot and run
   `grub-install --bootloader-id=myid --no-uefi-secure-boot`

See [Booting multiple Ubuntu versions with EFI](https://blog.lxgr.net/posts/2015/04/30/grub-efi-multiboot/)

Comment: @gdeff you saved the day! thanks :) adding  --no-uefi-secure-boot generates a different grubx64.efi file, which works around the problem of missing EFI/ubuntu folder

Comment: Then you have to disable 'secure boot' in UEFI ( what some people incorrectly still call BIOS ).