# Update the Kernel manually the way UKUU (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility) does

Tags: kernel, updates

I am Using Ubuntu 18.04.2
I have recently came to know about `systemd-boot` via https://askubuntu.com/a/1135735/739431

So, I dont have `grub` in my system. I am Using `systemd-boot` and happy with it..

I think Ubuntu 18.04.2 ships with Kernel 4.xx.x-xx-generic some version
{ex: `linux-headers-4.18.0-17-generic`}

to Update kernel I am using the tool UKUU (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility)

I am updating the Kernel every time when UKUU shows a notification about new Kernel Release like this..

[image]

Once I Choose "Install" It runs some commands like this and finally Installs the new Kernel in my System..

[image]

My Present Kernel

```
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ uname -r
5.0.11-050011-generic
pratap@i7-4770U:~$
```

***thoughts:***

my imagination is that UKUU tool is running some commands those are shown in above image, and I want to run those commands my self when I want to install specific Kernel Version..

***Question:***

Is it possible to run the commands manually that UKUU is doing in above Image by uninstalling the tool UKUU and successfully update the kernel? I Can check the latest Kernel Versions available from the website https://www.kernel.org/.

Comment: You might review [https://www.ostechnix.com/different-ways-to-update-linux-kernel-for-ubuntu/](https://www.ostechnix.com/different-ways-to-update-linux-kernel-for-ubuntu/) and [https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch08s06.html](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch08s06.html)

Comment: @CharlesGreen thanks for the links.. i will go through them.. mean while my main question concentrates on how to catch up commands what ukuu tool is doing and running them manually to successfully update the kernel..

Comment: Ukuu is downloading .deb files from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) and using `apt` or `gdebi` or `dpkg` to do the installation.  You will then need to modify grub if you want to run a particular installed kernel - `grub-customizer` might be of help for that.

Comment: @CharlesGreen seems your comment gave some clue.. if kernel can be installed i can run it.. i am looking for the part upto successful installation only.. i will try with your comment above and thanks for your time on this..

Comment: For me, as I run on older hardware, there is very little reason to push the kernel envelope.  If your interest is trying to learn more about kernels, I would suggest that you fire up a VM, and compile kernels *in the VM*.  I believe it is possible to squeeze more performance out of your system, but maintenance of such a system becomes non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135813/ubuntu-kernal-update-5-0-9) and the general consensus was that if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

I was particularly impressed with @Rinzwind answer:  ignore it ;-) I know it itches :D :D and it took me a year or 2 to accept to just ignore it. – Rinzwind Apr 21 at 17:17 and @heynnemma who advised:

> don't manually update it to 5.0.9. If this is a personal machine

Comment: @PRATAP fair comment but some may go where angles fear to tread encouraged by an answer to your question.