# "burn" Windows ISO to PARTITION on USB flash drive

Tags: uefi, windows-10, usb-drive, iso

I'm trying to build myself a multi-OS-boot USB flash drive, incl. Windows and Linux OS's. 
I am using Linux as the tool/utiliy machine.

Win10 ISO file `SW_DVD9_Win_Pro_Ent_Edu_N_10_1809_64-bit_English_MLF_X21-96501.ISO`

Content of ISO file when mounted):
[image]

I've tried the following:

- Using `dd if=my.iso of=/dev/sda3 bs=1M` to "burn" the ISO directly to the partition. But the partiton is somehow not readable by neither WinPE or EFI. Running `diskpart` in WinPE list the partition as `RAW`. Linux `lsblk` list the partition as `FS=udf`. EFI cannot see it when I try to browse to the partition for the efi boot file.
- Mounted the ISO file and tried both `tar` and `cp`  to copy all files and folders to the partition (formated as FAT32). But `tar` gave a lot of permissions errors on many of the files and `cp` couldn't copy the `/sources/install.wim` as it's above 4GB!
- Tried to copy files/foldes to the partition formated as NTFS. Now I could copy everything but now the EFI cannot read the \EFI subfolder so I have to do a `bcdboot` from WinPE, but it give the error `Failure when attempting to copy boot files`. Not sure if it cannot find source files or the target EFI partition on the usb flash drive (could not assign drive-letter to it from `diskpart`).

I ran out of ideas....help!

I guess I could just copy `c:\bootmgr.efi` to the EFI parition and make a boot entry for it (using `systemd-boot`) but it doesn't know which parititon Windows is installed to, i assume bscboot would fix that, right?

Comment: UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media
You can boot most Linux ISO directly, but not Windows with grub2's loopmount command. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c
& https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276498 All UEFI external drive boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.

Comment: I'm not talking about just making a bootable USB flash drive, my thread is way past that. And I'm using GPT.(no boot flag)....this is 2019 ;-) And after I got acquainted with systemd-boot I'll never go back to GRUB! So saying "All UEFI external drive boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi" is simply not true.